# Comparar strings de un array por su longitud

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles

Me encuentro aprendiendo JavaScript, y me topé con este ejercicio el cuál me está complicando la vida, ya que no sé cómo resolverlo. Si alguno pudiera ayudarme y decirme cómo podría resolverlo se lo agradecería

Esta es la consigna del ejercicio:

- Dados estos tres arrays:

​​​​carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];

herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];

omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

1. Define una variable llamada animals que referencie a los arrays anteriores.
2. Crea un bucle FOR que verifique en cada uno de los arrays cual es el animal con el nombre mas largo y al final, haz console.log() de un nuevo array de 3 posiciones, cada una con el animal mas largo de cada dieta respectivamente. (pista: animals[1][0] será 'elephant').

Dejo mi código:

```
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];


// 1:
let animalsMetodo1 = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];
let animalsMetodo2 = [].concat(carnivores, herbivores, omnivores);
// Estas fueron las dos formas que se me ocurrieron de resolver el ejercicio 1, en la primera aún tengo separados los grupos en 3 distintos arrays y en la segunda están todos los animales dentro del mismo array.

// 2:
```

Estuve intentando muchas cosas (hasta donde mi inteligencia y conocimiento llegan) pero no logro nada.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una función que compare la longitud de las palabras, y regrese la palabra más larga, y con esta función llenar el arreglo de respuesta. La función getLongestWord recibe el arreglo de palabras como parámetro, con un forEach (método utilizado para iterar por todo el arreglo) comparamos si la longitud de la palabra es más larga que la palabra anterior, y regresamos la palabra más larga

```js
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

const getLongestWord = (arr) => {
let longestWord = ""
  arr.forEach(element => {
if (element.length > longestWord.length){
    longestWord = element
}
  })
  return longestWord
}

const responseArray = []

responseArray.push(getLongestWord(carnivores))
responseArray.push(getLongestWord(herbivores))
responseArray.push(getLongestWord(omnivores))

console.log(responseArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si con "referencie a los arrays anteriores" se refiere a un array con todos los elementos o que solo contenga las las 3 arrays. Estos serían ambos casos:

```
//Contiene los elementos sueltos
var arrays = carnivores.concat(herbivores.concat(omnivores))
//Contiene los arrays
var arrays = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores]
```

Esta es la función que puedes utilizar para encontrar cual es el animal más largo de cada array

```
function encontrarAnimalMasLargo(animales){
    let animalMasLargo = "";
    animales.forEach(element => {
        if(element.length > animalMasLargo.length) animalMasLargo = element
    });
    return animalMasLargo;
}
```

Finalmente este es el bucle que pide en el segundo punto (utiliza el segundo caso de la variable `arrays`):

```
let respuesta = [];

arrays.forEach((element)=>{
    respuesta.push(encontrarAnimalMasLargo(element))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No solemos realizar ejercicios, pero viendo tu intento, se nota el desconocimiento.

En primer lugar, el ejercicio 1 lo que has realizado son dos arrays diferentes, la primera es una [Array multidimensional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#multi-dimensional_arrays) y la segunda una array simple, a la hora de iterar, por ejemplo en un bucle for los comportamientos son diferentes:

```js
//Declaramos dos arrays simples
let array1 = ["elem1","elem2","elem3"];
let array2 = ["elem4","elem5","elem6"];

//Generamos una array multidimensional y una simple
let multidimensional = [array1,array2];
let simple = array1.concat(array2);

//iteramos la multidimensional
for (let i = 0; i < multidimensional.length; i++){
  console.log("Resultado multidimensional",multidimensional[i])
}

//iteramos la simple
for (let i = 0; i < simple.length; i++){
  console.log("Resultado simple",simple[i])
}
```

Ya partiendo de conocer las diferencias entre una y otra, para obtener un resultado de cada array con el elemento con mas caracteres, necesitas una multidimensional y usando [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) ordenas según tamaño con la siguiente función:

```
var longest = arr.sort(
    function (a, b) {
        return b.length - a.length;
    }
)[0];
```

Quedandote una solución como esta:

```js
let carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
let herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
let omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

let animals = carnivores.concat(herbivores).concat(omnivores);
console.log("array simple con todos los animales: ",animals);

let arrayMultidimensional = [carnivores,herbivores,omnivores];
console.log("array multidimensional con todos los animales: ",arrayMultidimensional );

/*Generamos una array vacia para insertar el elemento de mayor 
tamaño en ella*/
let arrayMaxAnimal = []; 

for(let i = 0; i < arrayMultidimensional.length; i++){
  /*Como volvemos a necesitar que cada elemento sea una array
   declaramos una variable con una nueva array y ordenamos*/
    let bigger = new Array(arrayMultidimensional[i].sort(
  /*Comparamos los elementos y obtenemos el mayor*/
    function (a, b) {
        return b.length - a.length;
      }
  )[0]);
  console.log("el animal mas grande es: " + bigger);
  arrayMaxAnimal.push(bigger);
}

console.log("Resultado esperado elephant ->",arrayMaxAnimal[1][0]);
```